# .NET core 5.0 scaffolded Login page says "The returnUrl field is required" (Blazor Server-Side)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a .net 5.0 preview 7 project running Blazor server, and Identity login was working fine, until I scaffolded the Identity Login page. Now I get `The returnUrl field is required.` form error message as soon as the login page loads

When I debug `OnGetAsync` method in Login.cshtml.cs, it shows that returnUrl does have a value.

I have `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in csproj in case that could make a difference.

Here's the Login.cshtml.cs and Login.cshtml file content exactly as scaffolded, and causing the issue. Any ideas what could be wrong?

```cs
// Login.cshtml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using POS.WebAdmin.Data.Model;

namespace POS.WebAdmin.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, 
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// Login.cshtml
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post">
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                            <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
            <hr />
            @{
                if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">this article</a>
                            for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally found the solution [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22656#issuecomment-640650945)

Changing the OnGetAsync `returnUrl` parameter to nullable solves the issue:

from
`public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)`

to
`public async Task OnGetAsync(string? returnUrl = null)`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting modelState for the returnUrl invalid. Making the string nullable fixed that issue as well.